# How can I prevent a page break when defining AtBeginEnvironment?

Tags: environments

I am trying to add a horizontal bar before my theorem environment, using

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\medskip \noindent {\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}\nopagebreak}
```

However, the horizontal bar can still end up at the bottom of a page.  Is there any way I can enforce keeping it attached to the first line of the environment?

Update:  The \needspace answer suggested by John Kormylo worked!  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Can you please post code we can compile to illustrate the problem? That is, a Minimal Working Example (MWE) starting `\documentclass ...` and ending `\end{document}` (or equivalent if this was not LaTeX). That makes it much easier for people to help.

Comment: At a guess, `\medskip\par` might help, but it depends what else is happening. I'm guessing you've got a paragraph break after the line. The `\medskip` won't do anything until the paragraph ends.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The easy solution would be to use `\needspace` (needspace package) to force a prage break early, and `\BeforeBeginEnvironment`.